# Align div below other elements and align its text vertically

Tags: html, css

I've got the following issue. I've got a div where I'm unable to vertically align its text and also unable to place it below other divs.
My div:

```
<div th:text="#{mailContent.resetBtn}" style="
border: 0;
color: white;
height: 25px;
display: table-cell;
background-color: #FD8907;
cursor: pointer;
border-radius: 2px;
outline: 0;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif; 
font-size: 16px; 
padding: 50px;
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align: middle;
"> 
    RESET PASSWORD
 </div>
```

It ends up looking like this

[image]

I want it to be below the text that says "click on the following button...".
And I also find it impossible to set some padding to the text and centering it. 
(Padding there is exaggeratedly set to 50px but it doesn't work anyways).

Full code:
https://pastebin.com/NqgXs4tD

Comment: the link shows it is in a table form, so you need to consider putting elements in rows using `tr` and `td`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `<td>` inside a `<tr>` instead of `div`

```css
#title{
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
}

#pass-content {
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#btn-info {
  padding: 20px 0 10px 0;
  color: #153643;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

#btn {
  border: 0;
  color: white;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #FD8907;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 2px;
  outline: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="title">
    <td>Password Reset</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pass-content"> This is an email to reset the password for the account 123@gmail.com. If you don't wish to change your password please ignore this email. </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="btn-info">
    <td>
      Click on the following button:
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="btn">
    <td>RESET PASSWORD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flex-box as display, so you can align it horizontal and vertical.

Also you use display 2 times. And you should sort ur rules..

And because HTML5 exist you should never ever use table for design and only for tables. Did you validate your file? You open a new table tag while the old one isn't closed.

Answer (score 1):

With `display: flex` and `align-items: center` you can vertically align the content elements (and text). And with `order: {number}` you can re-order the child elements of a flexbox element.